# C# overwrite file with empty file when trying to upload (ftp)

Tags: c#, ftp

I am trying to upload text file over ftp, and when I run program, it empty my file and then upload it.
I don't know why... May it overwrite or something else... Here is my code:

This is in Main class

```
        /* Create Object Instance */
        ftp ftpClient = new ftp(@"ftp://sportcaffe.me", "sport***", "*****");

        /* Upload a File */
        ftpClient.upload("public_html/test.txt", @"C:\Users\Lazar\Desktop\test.txt");
```

And here is ftp class function code:

```
/* Upload File */
    public void upload(string remoteFile, string localFile)
    {
        try
        {
            /* Create an FTP Request */
            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
            /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            /* When in doubt, use these options */
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
            ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
            /* Open a File Stream to Read the File for Upload */
            FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);
            /* Buffer for the Downloaded Data */
            byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            /* Upload the File by Sending the Buffered Data Until the Transfer is Complete */
            try
            {
                while (bytesSent != 0)
                {
                    ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);
                    bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
            /* Resource Cleanup */
            localFileStream.Close();
            ftpStream.Close();
            ftpRequest = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
        return;
    }
```

There is no errors and warnings...

first  I write something in my file and save, then when I run program my file is empty and that empy file has been uploaded...

i used this code http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/443588/Simple-Csharp-FTP-Class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);
```

I hope I don't need to spell this out too clearly but the above line is being told to *create* a file. To quote the docs: "Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the file already exists, it will be overwritten."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx has a list of the options you can use instead here. `FileMode.Open` should be good for your needs (it will open the file and if the file doesn't exist throw an exception).

Answer (score 1):

Solved

FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);
replace FileMode.Create by FileMode.Open

Comment: Why did you post an answer? This is exactly what the existing answer recommends, you should just accept that one.